# Creating a list of column averages from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I asked this before, but I'm still not sure why I get this error when I try to test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

new_list.append(new_list[i] + num_list[i])
   builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Here is the file:

```
Last Name,First Name,Student No.,uTORid,A1,A2,A3,A4
Smith, Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

I want to get the class average of each assignment. Like the sum of 99, 11, and 78 and then find the average of that. Same with the other assignments.

```
def class_avg(open_file):
'''(file) -> list of float
Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the 
order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments 
per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
class_avg -> [assignment_1_class_avg, assignment_2_class_avg...]
[62.666666666666664, 56.0, 59.333333333333336, 66.0]
'''
new_list = []
count = 0
for line in open_file:
    num_list = line.split(',')[4:]
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        new_list.append(count)
        new_list.append(new_list[i] + num_list[i])
        count +=1
        avg = sum(float(new_list))/len(new_list)
return new_list
```

Comment: skip the first line with the headers? Youre Adding count (==0) to your new_list, then you add "A1" ( a string, first line of the file, 4th param in split) to it. + is not defined for int + string. Exactlly what the error tells you.

Comment: This is CSV, pandas is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner) stated in the comments, you are adding an int and a string together, causing the error. Using the pandas library for CSV reading is really useful for situations like this one:

```
import pandas as pd

def class_avg(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    not_grades = 4  # Number of attributes that are not grades
    total_attributes = len(df.columns)
    avg = []

    for i in range(not_grades, total_attributes):
        avg.append(df.iloc[:, i].mean(axis=0))  # Get the column by index and calculate its mean

    return avg
```

This code does exactly what you want. You need to state how many attributes come before the grades though, because they are not the only ones with numbers (otherwise it would calculate the mean of the student's number as well).

Comment: dows panda automatically skip the header row? nice

Comment: (df.iloc[:, i] what does this mean? and the file was already read from a previous function, so we don't need to do it again. And what is df?

Comment: Yes, it uses the header row as the DataFrame header(column attribute).

Comment: We dont need to read the header file cuz it was already read in another function.

Comment: @bigd, when you do `for line in open_file` you are reading the file object all over again, which essentially makes no difference from reading it again with pandas(but pandas is much nicer for data). `df.iloc[:, i]` means we are reading all the lines from the i th column. If you would like to read only the first line from that column, it would be something like `df.iloc[0, 1]`. When using only the ":" we are saying to it that we want everything from the first element to the last.

Comment: I mean the header was already skipped in a previous function.

Comment: @bigd, no problem. Just close the file and pass the file path to the `class_avg()` function and it will work. If you are saving the file again without the header, you can just use this line instead `df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)`.

Comment: A bit, but could I get rid of the first line, since it was already read and skipped in a previous function?

Comment: @bigd, as I have said, you can just close the file before calling the function and pass the file path instead. That way you can open and read the file with Pandas, and work your way out. After the function returns, you can open your file again(for whatever reason you would want to do so).

Comment: Is there another way to define df without reading the header?

Comment: Yes, just like I said in the previous comments you could use `df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)`